# define the return type for udf in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions, return-type

I was creating a UDF that based on below function:

```
def return_output(column):
    return {'features':{'site':'a.com', 'test':column, 'test_vocab':['a','b','c']}
```

but I am not sure how to define the return type

one example for column would be {"sentence":[0,1,2],"another_one":[0,1,2]}

so the final output would be looking like below:

```
{'features':{'home_page':'a.com', 'test':{"sentence":[0,1,2],"another_one":[0,1,2]}
, 'test_vocab':['a','b','c']}
```

How am I supposed to define the return type for this output?

Comment: Should it be the type *String* or *Struct*?

Comment: it should be. struct type

Answer (score 0):

This looks very *JSON* like so the correct type should be `StructType` - you can read more about it here - https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.types.StructType.html#structtype